# Any way to re-run the chef-solo provisioner on a packer built machine?

Tags: chef, provisioning, chef-solo, packer

I'm building VirtualBox machines using Packer and the chef-solo provisioner.  Is there a way to re-run chef from within the VM as recipes are updated without needing to re-run `packer build`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out.  It looks like packer sets up everything I need in `packer-chef-solo`.  I needed to manually copy in the updated recipes, and then run the same command packer originally ran, `sudo chef-solo --no-color -c /tmp/packer-chef-solo/solo.rb -j /tmp/packer-chef-solo/node.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a virtulbox.box file as an input for packer builds.

Use one packerbase.json which does your online boot and installs your basic packages and then have a packerlatest.json that build using packerbase.json as a starting point.